# Bootstrap & Jquery set nav bar item active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set a nav bar item active when selected through this scrpt

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it does not work

see this

http://www.bootply.com/eKZjSelT8s

Comment: Post your HTML and a fiddle or bootply example please.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/eKZjSelT8s

Comment: So you need something like this http://www.bootply.com/pN2peVhF3V?